# Notation for the local polynomial of a Weil representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $\rho$ be a Weil representation over a local field $K$.
In [this paper](https://research-information.bristol.ac.uk/files/84756616/_Journal_f_r_die_reine_und_angewandte_Mathematik_Euler_factors_determine_local_Weil_representations.pdf), I found the following defintion of the local polynomial:

$$ P(\rho,T) = \det(1-\operatorname{Frob}_K^{-1}T | \rho^{I_K}). $$

Could you please explain me what this notation means? I am especially confused by the $\rho^{I_K}$ at the end. I just know that $I_K$ is the inertia subgroup of the absolute Galois group $G_K$. And I assume that $T$ is just the variable of the polynomial, right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\rho^{I_K}$ denotes the subspace of $\rho$ fixed by inertia. Since Frobenius is well defined on this subspace, we can calculate its characteristic polynomial, as a linear map acting on this subspace. If $\rho$ is unramified, then $\rho = \rho^{I_K},$ and this polynomial will have dimension $\dim \rho$. But in general, its dimension will be smaller.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I understood that correctly: Let $\rho : G \to \operatorname{GL}_n(V)$. Then $\rho^{I_K} = V^{I_K} = \{ x \in V | gx = x \forall g \in I_K \}$, is that correct? And why is the Frobenius element well-defined on this subspace? An Frobenius element is an element in $G_K$, so I do not really understand the transition to the well-definedness.

Comment: The Frobenius element is the canonical (topological) generator of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline k/k)\cong G_K/I_K$. We can lift this Frobenius element to $G_K$, but doing so involves a choice. However, on $\rho^{I_K}$, the action of Frobenius is independent of that choice.